# strange code appears in terminal

Tags: command-line, apt, bashrc

So I was trying to install openfoam on ubuntu 14.04 and there are two problems I need your help with. One, a strange code appears everytime I run the terminal(I've attached a picture of it). Two, I cannot run openfoam, an error occurs, a picture of which is also attached. Please help, I am new to ubuntu. [image: Problem 1] [image: Problem 2]

Comment: This refers to the second issue you were having (openfoam):
<br />
It appears that a file is missing in the openfoam, specifically dealing with the file/folder controlDict and is unable to execute as a result. Have you tried redownloading openfoam or replacing the file/folder with a new copy?

Comment: Hello Chris, I haven't tried that. I wanted to know if this was a problem with the installation or a problem with ubuntu before I did anything. Would you suggest me to reinstall openFoam and this would solve it?

Comment: This seems like an issue with the installation. Try reinstalling openFoam and you should be able to run it with no problems after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these suggestions may work for you, but here's what I would try first:

Regarding the first issue, there's a hidden file in your home folder called `.bashrc`. Open a terminal and type `ls -a` which means "list files -all of them" and you should see the file. The contents of this file are executed every time you open your terminal, and I suspect that the offending line may have inadvertently been appended to it.

Again from the command line, type `gedit .bashrc` to open the file in a text editor, then search (ctrl-f) for the word ELMER4.0. If it shows up, comment out the line it occurs on by preceeding it with a `#`. Save the file (ctrl-s), then close the terminal and re-open it again. The error should be gone.

For the second error, the first thing I would do is to type `sudo apt-get -f install` into the command line. This will list any unmet depedencies any currently installed packages may have. If anything is missing, you can attempt to install it directly with `sudo apt-get install [package-name]`.